# A DRY React Native Redux Async Example

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

There's a good Redux Async example on the redux [GitHub page](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async) however it's written for one API request.

In the real world there is a good chance that many API calls will need to be made and I'm hunting for the best way the achieve this as DRY as possible.